# MVC Web App link opens a new tab on Safari on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, url, model-view-controller

I'm using a barcode scanning app called pic2Shop within a MVC application to pass back a barcode via a call back.

The issue is each new scan causes a new tab to be opened in Safari on the iPhone. So 10 scans ten tabs.

I'm using window.location.href but have tried window.open(path,"_self") where path is the callback url

HTML

```
<span class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-hidden="true" type="button" id="barcodeDropdown" onclick="getScan()" data-toggle=" dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
```

Script

```
window.location.href = "pic2shop://scan?callback=http%3A%2F%2F" + window.location.hostname + "%2Ffantail%2FProduct%2FDetails%2FEAN";
```

Comment: On the latest iOS `window.location.href` opens up the new URL on the same tab. Just out of curiosity, I see you're using the "pic2shop" protocol, what happens if you try a normal `window.location.href = http://...`? I give a wild guess here: the pic2shop app opens by default a new tab.